# Spotify Web API Error 400: "Only valid bearer authentication supported"

Tags: node.js, spotify, webapi

I'm trying to use the Spotify Web API to search for songs through node, but it keeps sending me a status 400 error with the message: "Only valid bearer authentication supported". This is my code:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let searchurl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?";

  request.post(
    {
      url: searchurl,
      data: {
        q: "john",
        type: "album",
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Basic " +
          Buffer.from(client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString("base64"),
      },
      method: "POST",
    },

    function (e, r, body) {
      console.log(body);
    }
  );
});
```

I don't understand what the issue is and have read through everything I could find, but got nowhere. Am I supposed to use a different access key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Authorisation Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) for Spotify, you can use the **Client Id** and **Client Secret** to get an **Access Token** and it is that you send as part of an **Authorization** header when making the request to the [Search for an Item](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/) endpoint you're trying to use